# Convergence of densities vs. other modes of convergence for random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, density-function

While I was summarizing the relations between different modes of convergence for random variables, I got stuck at the convergence of the densities...
My question:

> $X_n \to X$ a.s. (or in $L_1$/ in probability) $\quad
>  \overset{?}{\Rightarrow} \quad f_{X_n} \to f_X$ a.e. (or in any other
>   sense)

where $X,X_n: (\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)\to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ measurable, with laws $\mu_{X_n},\mu_X << \lambda$ [Lebesgue measure] (in order to admit density functions $f_{X_n}, f_X$  on $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216491/convergence-in-probability-and-pointwise-convergence-of-densities

Comment: thank you, that disproves the "a.s $\Rightarrow$ density a.e" and the "convergence in probability $\Rightarrow$ density a.e" implications